# Can't add items to listbox from another class C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to add items to listbox from another class,the information pass to the function but the listbox doesn't seem to update. this is my code:

```
Main class (FORM) :

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // the function that updates the listbox
    public void logURI(string OutputLog, string Information, string JOB)
    {
        try
        {
            listBox1.BeginUpdate();
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + JOB + " " + Information);
            listBox1.Items.Add("1");
            listBox1.EndUpdate();
            textBox1.Text = JOB;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Second Class:

```
public class FtpFileSystemWatcherTS
{
     Form1 logs = new Form1();
     logs.logURI( "", "Found folder modefied today (" + FileName.TrimEnd(), ") ElectricaTS"); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide some more information about your second class and its usage of the form. Are you showing the form you create in the class FtpFileSystemWatcherTS or is there more than one instance of the form?

Comment: Does textBox1 update? If you run your code from the Visual Studio debugger, do you see any error messages in the Output window?

Comment: You don't need to call BeginUpdate and EndUpdate since you're only adding 2 items to the list box.

Comment: I can show you all the class if you want, I'm not showing the form in the second class, only making an instance so I can send my information to the forms listbox.

Comment: NO i don't get any error message, if I hover over "JOB", or "Information", it has the correct content, but the listbox dosen't show the items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the `Form` from within the other class - any changes you make for the `Form`'s children will not be displayed because it is another form that is being shown. Instead, you want to either pass the `Form` instance that is running into the `FtpFileSystemWatcher` class, so that it can access the `Form.Controls` property, or give it direct access to the `ListBox` or source of the `ListBox` items.

**EDIT**

Suggestion:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private FtpFileSystemWatcher mWatcher;

    // ... some code ...

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create a new watcher and give it access to this form
        mWatcher = new FtpFileSystemWatcher(this);
    }

    // ... Logging code ...
}

public class FtpFileSystemWatcher
{
    private Form1 mMainForm;

    public FtpFileSystemWatcher(Form1 mainForm)
    {
        mMainForm = mainForm;
    }

    public void Log()
    {
        mMainForm.logUri(...);
    }
}
```

This is just an example of some code format that you could use to give the `FtpFileSystemWatcher` access to the running `Form`. This will be setup when the `Form` is run (assuming you have it running correctly). You should then see your desired updates.

Comment: I did set the "Modifiers" listbox to public, or it's some other way to give direct acces to the listbox?

Comment: That should give it direct access, but that's not the issue. The issue in the example (from what I can see) is that you are trying to update the value on a `Form` that isn't the `Form` being run.

Answer (score 0):

you can use inheritance easily since the procedure's access modifier is set to public

Main class (FORM) :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

   // the function that updates the listbox
   public void logURI(string OutputLog, string Information, string JOB)
    {
        try
        {
            listBox1.BeginUpdate();
            listBox1.Items.Add("0");
            listBox1.Items[0] = DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + JOB + " " + Information;
            listBox1.Items.Add("1");
            listBox1.EndUpdate();
            textBox1.Text = JOB;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

}

```
public class FtpFileSystemWatcherTS : Form1
{
     logURI( "", "Found folder modefied today (" + FileName.TrimEnd().toString(), ") ElectricaTS"); 
}
```

Comment: just use
: Form1
after second class's name ,so you can access to its parent class's methods and properties.also keep in mind when you do like your way it actually updates not the real listbox instead its copy.

Comment: there is another way that you can pass the listbox as a parameter to the second class and add items from the second class. so it will actually update the real one.

Comment: How can I do that... I'm trying for 3-4 houres to figure this out.. I'm very frustated, can you show my where to modify ?

Comment: then the only way is update the listbox from the second class (child class) by passing a Listbox parameter to it.

Comment: how can i pass a listbox parameter to it ?