# Can't add strings to listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Hi i'm trying to collect output of [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/467361/Using-Clipboard-Csharp-Wrapper-inside) library into listbox.

Here's part of code from the test project, with i've tried to modify:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    D.Net.Clipboard.ClipboardManager Manager;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Manager = new D.Net.Clipboard.ClipboardManager(this);
        Manager.Type = D.Net.Clipboard.ClipboardManager.CheckType.Text;
        Manager.OnNewTextFound += (sender, eventArg) =>
        {
            button1.Text = eventArg;            //just testing, working correctly
            listBox1.Items.Add(eventArg);       //does not show neither result nor any error
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("New text found in clipboard : {0}", eventArg));
        };
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("test");             //working correctly
    }
}
```

Problem is when i trying to add item into the list it does nothing, and further lines of code (in this function) don't run at all.

I tried to fix it thru some custom classes and different expressions but nothing worked for me (yes, I'm a noob). Also tried to do it with textBox, result is the same, but text on buttons changes as it should.

Looks like completely lame problem, but i've spent almost 5 hours by googling, reading microsoft documentation, SO, and closest i can get is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759934/cant-add-items-to-listbox-from-another-class-c-sharp) as i can see stuff suggested there already implemented.

Comment: Try using `listBox1.Items.Add(eventArg.ToString());` and see if that works.

Comment: `button1.Text = eventArg;` won't even compile for me.

Comment: @Grant Winney yep, working as it should
@ dub stylee, no it does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnNewTextFound` event is firing on a separate thread from the UI, so your attempt to update the UI is failing. An exception is thrown in the other thread, aborting the rest of that method, but your UI thread keeps executing.

You'll have to call `Invoke()` in order to execute the code back on the UI thread:

```
listBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { listBox1.Items.Add(eventArg); }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding EventArgs to the Items list for the ListBox. Is there an eventArgs.[someString] that you can add?

Comment: Nope, VS suggested just standart operations and in library code is nothing announced but `string text` as i can see.

Comment: I see that now. The delegate is declared with the second parameter as a string. My next question is when does the event get fired? Could eventArg ever be null? Perhaps add a null check to only add items with a value. ie. If (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventArg)) { listBox1.Items.Add(eventArg); }

Answer (score -1):

You cannot add items to a listbox during the construction of the form.  You need to move the code into the Load event.